# TFS build .net Core with nuget restore end in error

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

While trying to build on tfs a .net Code 2.2 solution have a nuget restore task. it's trying to connect to our internal feeds. Then it fail. In the build logs we have :

> error : Unable to load the service index for source http://internalSource/index.json. [D:\dummy.csproj]
>
> error :   No credentials are available in the security package [D:\dummy.csproj]

Looking at TFS generated files, it's not using the credential we declare in our solution. 
Our nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="PackageSTN" value="http://internal/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <PackageSTN>
        <add key="Username" value="user" />
        <add key="Password" value="pwd" />
    </PackageSTN> 
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The one on TFS the build give us:

```
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True"/>
    <add key="automatic" value="True"/>
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <clear/>
  <add key="PackageSTN" value="http://internal/index.json"/></packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)"/>
  </activePackageSource>
    <packageSourceCredentials>       
        <PackageSTN>
            <add key="Username" value="VssSessionToken"/>
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="Too Big to be display"/>
        </PackageSTN>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Seem like it's trying to use some `VssSessionToken` TFS account to log on.

In addition we replace the %APPDATA% nuget.config on the server with the one with our credential, in case it will have a look inside, no luck as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we did a powershell script, to by-pass this :/

```
try
{
    $solutionSln = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY + $env:solutionSln
    $nugetConfig = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY + $env:nugetConfig

    Write-Host "dotnet restore $solutionSln --configfile  $nugetConfig --verbosity Detailed --no-cache"
    dotnet restore $solutionSln --configfile  $nugetConfig --verbosity Detailed --no-cache
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> TFS build .net Core with nuget restore end in error

As we know, when we select the option `Feeds in my NuGet.config`, we also need provide the `Credentials for feeds outside this account/collection`:

[image]

If we use the token we got from `CredentialProvider.VSS.exe` in the field "Personal Access Token" in the NuGet connection window, we may got the issue like you. The token we got from `CredentialProvider.VSS.exe` is a short-lived token, you could replace it with PAT (Personal Access Token) to check if it work for you.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902864/how-to-restore-nuget-packages-from-a-private-azure-devops-feed) for some more details.

Besides, if you are using the old nuget.exe, you can use the task `NuGet Tool Installer` to update it.

If above not help you, please share your build definition about nuget restore task and the steps how to add the Credentials for feeds outside this account/collection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, we just tried what you proposed with the PAT token, and as well using credential in Basic Authentication tab, still the same result. When you ask for the build definition, you mean the json ?

Comment: @SylvainLucas, The screenshot about your build definition for your nuget restore task, erase your personal information.

Comment: Finally we manage, see my other answer, I will mark as resolved tomorrow, thanks for your time

Comment: @SylvainLucas, You are welcome :). I am sorry that I did not give you the most accurate answer in the first time. Thank you for your sharing.